# Rectification-projective2d

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, projective-geometry

Does any one know how this function (projective2d) works? I have a code for rectification and my Matlab have error with this function (Undefined function 'projective2d' for input arguments of type 'double'), however I think it should work for double input. 
In the other hand when I search it in the help, there is not any function with this name. It is a part of my code:

```
[t1, t2] = estimateUncalibratedRectification(fMatrix, ...
  inlierPoints1.Location, inlierPoints2.Location, size(I2));
I1Rect = imwarp(I1, projective2d(t1), 'OutputView', imref2d(size(I1)));
I2Rect = imwarp(I2, projective2d(t2), 'OutputView', imref2d(size(I2)));
```

I would appreciate if anyone help me.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/projective2dclass.html), `projective2D` requires a 3x3 matrix, if given input.

Comment: It may be not present in your MATLAB version (or you don't have the right toolbox, or the toolbox is not on your MATLAB path).

Answer (score 0):

`projective2d` is a constructor of a MATLAB class, which returns an object that encapsulates a projective transformation. The error you are getting means that you have an older version of MATLAB, which doesn't have it. Try using `imtransform` instead of `imwarp`, and pass `t1` and `t2` directly into it, without creating `projective2d` objects.